# Linking problem with R package AsioHeaders

Tags: rcpp, asio

I am using Asio in a Rcpp package, and am therefore using the package AsioHeaders.

I have added BH and AsioHeaders in the "LinkingTo" part of the DESCRIPTION file of my package. I have also added comments

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(AsioHeaders)]]
```

in my code. So normally, the linking should be fine when compiling the package.

And it is when I compile it on Linux. But when trying to compile it on Windows, I get linking errors that are solved by linking `-lws2_32` and `-lwsock32`.

I am thus wondering, whether I should edit the `Makevars` file so that these are linked on Windows but ignored on Linux, or if I have done something wrong using AsioHeaders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsioHeaders maintainer here.  Quick questions:

1. Which version of AsioHeaders? It just updated at CRAN.  Is this a change from the new version (which would suprise me ...)?
2. Make sure you are not accidentally using Asio functionality from Boost *which will require linking*. See  the three packages using AsioHeaders.

*If* your package is truly header-only then `LinkingTo:` is all you need. R will find the header directories for you.  In particular, you do not need link instructions in `src/Makevars*` because, well, header-only.

Also, you probably meant `//` forward slashes for your C++ comments above...

Comment: 1. I use version 1.16.1-1. It is a fresh install therefore I do not know if it behaved the same with older versions. 2. I compile with the compiler bundled in R, and as far as I know, boost is not even installed on my machine, so I think there is little chance it uses Asio from there.

Comment: (I edited the comment slashes in my question, I knew something was odd there...)

Comment: To be more precise, I use the compiler from `rtools`. And I have compared what I have with what is in the `ipaddress` package from CRAN, it seems that only thing they do to use `AsioHeaders` is to add it in the `LinkingTo:` line, which I also do. But I can compile the package, so I must be missing something somewhere, if I find it I will report it here...

Comment: Sorry but you will have to debug your problem -- we can't tell without seeing the code.  You *do* have an existence proof in the three packages `iptools`, `ipaddress` and `websocket` that are using `AsioHeaders` without a linking requirement and work perfectly well if done right---including on Windows via `Rtools`.  All it takes is one function requiring linking, and I can only guess you are accessing such a function.

Comment: I think I was indeed trying to use Asio from Boost. However, after looking more carefully at the package `ipaddress`, I saw that they use a `Makervars.win` file to link `-lws2_32` and `-lwsock32`. Adding this allows compilation on Windows, I don't know if it is intended, but it seems this link is unavoidable for compilation on this platform.

Comment: I suspected that mix.  And yes, maybe on Windows you need those (to get us more POSIX behaviour that may be a given on Unix/Linux/macOS). Now that we know, just add them to `src/Makevars.win` as every Windows will have the library.

Comment: I should probably set up a minimal package `AsioHeaderExample` to just parse an Ip address or alike and see if it passes on Windows with/without the linking example.

Comment: A minimal package would indeed be a good starting point for newcomers like me. Going through an entire existing package makes it easy to mix things up. Anyway, thank you for your amazing work as always.

Comment: @nicodr Yes indeed -- and here it is: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppasioexample  And you were quite right: On Windows one must use these two linker arguments to add the two Windows system libraries providing the required functionality common on Unix.